# Worksheet_Change Event Stops Working after Another Macro Runs

Tags: excel, vba, events

When I run another macro this one stops working. The only way to get it back on track is to run the following command in the immediate window.

```
Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim lastrow As String, x, row, irow, column, total As Double
    lastrow = Range("B8").End(xlDown).Value + 7

    Range("Pump_design[Total Pipe losses from plantroom]").ClearContents
    For Each row In Columns("FB")
        For irow = 8 To lastrow
            total = 0
            For column = 6 To 153
                x = Cells(irow, column).Value
                If Not IsEmpty(x) Then
                    total = total + Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(x, Sheets("Pump Design").Range("Pump_design"), 155, False)
                End If
            Next column
            Cells(irow, "FB") = total
            If Cells(irow, "FB") = 0 Then Cells(irow, "FB").ClearContents
        Next irow
        row = irow + 1
    Next row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Here is the code that makes the above macro stop working:

```
Sub delete_row()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim LastrowPD As Long, PDi As String, PDj As Integer
    LastrowPD = Sheets("Pump Design").ListObjects("pump_design").Range.Rows.Count
    PDi = LastrowPD - 1
    If IsNumeric(PDi) Then PDj = Val(PDi)
    If PDj = 1 Then Exit Sub
    Sheets("Pump Design").Activate
    Sheets("Pump Design").ListObjects("pump_design").Range.Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows(PDj).Delete
    Range("A1").Select
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Please format the code so we can READ it. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is probably on your other macro. (And btw this one is an event function, not really a macro). You are probably deactivating event in this other macro, do not forget to reactive them at the end.

Comment: Your `row = irow + 1` contradicts with `For Each row in...`. This means that `row` is managed by the `For` statement and should not be manipulated by you.

Comment: @pAul Ogilvie what would you advise in this case? And sorry but what do you mean by format the code? thanks

Comment: @VincentG Yes I am using it as an event function as I do not want to click on a button every time that I am entering data. I want the calculation to be done instantaneously. and to respond to your comment, my other macro only delete the last row of three tables.

Comment: "Formatting the code" means to use indentations hat show the logic of loops and If statements. I just did that [for you]. Of course you have seen other programmers do that, so why didn't you do that?

Comment: Looks good, never thought about it I programming only for 4 weeks. I will do the same in my code. Thanks for the advice. Any idea on where could come from my problem?
I just removed the `row = irow + 1` and the code works. However I am still getting the same issue with the fact that my macro stops and I have to run it again by typing `application.enableevents = true` in Immediate

Comment: `Sub delete_row()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Dim LastrowPD As Long, PDi  As String, PDj As Integer
LastrowPD = Sheets("Pump Design").ListObjects("pump_design").Range.Rows.Count
PDi = LastrowPD - 1
If IsNumeric(PDi) Then PDj = Val(PDi)
If PDj = 1 Then Exit Sub
Sheets("Pump Design").Activate
Sheets("Pump Design").ListObjects("pump_design").Range.Select
Selection.ListObject.ListRows(PDj).Delete
Range("A1").Select
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub` Here is the macro which makes the above one crashing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 If PDj = 1 Then Exit Sub
```

This is the problem.  Because you are exiting the sub you are not turning events back on.  Instead you can invert the logic:

```
If PDj <> 1 Then 
    Sheets("Pump Design").Activate
    Sheets("Pump Design").ListObjects("pump_design").Range.Select
    Selection.ListObject.ListRows(PDj).Delete
    Range("A1").Select
end if
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Comment: I found out in the meantime but thanks anyway for your help. It was the answer ;) Have a good day cheers

Answer (score 0):

Without saying this is a solution, I want to point out a few errors:

```
Dim lastrow As String, x, row, irow, column, total As Double
```

In the above line, `lastrow` is a `String` and `total` is a `Double`. All other vaiables are `Variant`. I am sure that is not what you mean.

With `lastrow` a `String`, I wonder what its value will be when executing:

```
lastrow = Range("B8").End(xlDown).Value + 7
```

In your loop logic:

```
For Each row In Columns("FB")
    For irow = 8 To lastrow
        ....
    Next irow
    row = irow + 1
Next row
```

I wonder what the `irow` loop will do with `lastrow` being a `String`. At the end of this loop, `irow`, being a `Variant` and so could be a `String`, will be one larger than `lastrow` (now assuming it is an `Integer`). You then execute

```
    row = irow + 1
Next row
```

but since `row` is managed by the `For Each` statement, either this will totally confuse the `Each`, or the statement has no effect.

I suggest you first clear all these errors and then check the code's functioning again.

Comment: Might be useful if you could have a look at the file directly. Here is the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/zdpxd07ebhm8m80/Pressure%20drop.xlsx?dl=0